# Running multiple SparkContexts in a single JVM, or making multiple JVMs in a intellij env

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to make a local spark environment in Intellij for the dev/test of a Spark application that maintains multiple local spark sessions, one for each executors.

So, my dev. environment should allows multiple sparkContexts on a single JVM or runs multiple JVMs, in order to mimic the executors and their local sessions.

Could you recommend any possible way for this purpose?

Follow are my code and errors.

````
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing")
     .setMaster("local-cluster[8, 2, 128]") // or .setMaster("local[*]")
     .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)



[Executor task launch worker for task 2] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkContext:    
   Multiple running SparkContexts detected in the same JVM!
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). 
   To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. 
   The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:126)```
````

Comment: the message tells you your idea is flawed

Comment: @thebluephantom 
The system works find in a real clusters.., and actually not mine :). What I'm trying to is just making local dev env. So what you advised by 'idea' is.. not to make dev env in a local machine?